# Sudden disengament of clutch in low rpms

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, yamaha

I have bought a new Yamaha MT15, completed 200+ kms in it. But sometimes when I am stuck in traffic, I engage the clutch and gradually let it go but occasionally the clutch dis-engages and I am thrown forwards.After that i find no problem in the clutch. I have been facing these suddenly. What may be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds as though the clutch itself is sticking unengaged as you release the lever, then suddenly pops free, allowing the clutch to fully engage rapidly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What might be causing the problem? I asked the service center guys at yamaha,but they asked me to wait till the first servicing and also they couldn't reproduce the problem since it happens randomly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I really wouldn't know ... I'm just theorizing from how you described it. A randomly sticking clutch is all I could come up with (but nothing you probably haven't already thought of). If the clutch just happens to be in the right position when you try to let off and it sticks there is about the only thing I can add which might be pertinent. Maybe a flat spot or a protrusion where the clutch is at when it sticks? It may be something which would break in over time, but really, I'm sure it sucks when it does what it does.

Comment: Can it be the clutch cable or something? Since when it happens, the clutch lever feels very soft for 2-3 seconds and since this is a new bike also.

Comment: Did you check online if anyone with the same bike experiences the same issues? I believe mt15 is fairly new. Maybe they messed up something at the factory.